# Vim say "Not an editor command:..."

Tags: vim, macros

I record macro a try play it

`qm5dd2lva>d$va<jVGdq` and try play `:@m` but vim say me - `E492: Not an editor command: 5dd2lva>d$va<jVGd`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 22):

You don't need the `:` when replaying the macro. Just type `@m`.

Comment: @Igor: `:@` actually does something similar - it executes the contents of the register as a command, i.e. as if you'd typed `:` first. This can be useful too - but in your case, you wanted to perform those actions in normal mode, not command mode. (Also, since this worked, you might want to click the check mark to accept the answer!)